# Math font change for subscript only

Tags: fonts, math-mode, tex-core

**Goal:** I want a macro that changes the math font of only subscript and superscript.  In TeX terms, I think this means I want to change only S, S' styles, which are typeset using scriptfont.

Graphically, I'd want

```
\bfscript{v_i}
```

to be displayed as `$v_{\mathbf{i}}$`.

**Tries:** I've been trying to do it the TeX way; that is, something like

```
\def\bfscript#1{\hbox{$\scriptfont0=\tenbf #1$}}
```

but this fails miserably, as scriptfont and the likes seem completely ignored by LaTeX.  It seems that LaTeX only allows to make distinctions on the fontsize, with `\DeclareMathSizes`.

**Nota:** I was first interested in this as a real-life case, but I'm not even sure I'll need it any longer; I'm just really wondering what the answer is.

Comment: `\tenbf` is unknown in LaTeX, which uses quite a complicated way to set up math families. I'd say that `$v_\mathbf{i}$` is really the best choice.

Comment: There are many other places where script style is used (fractions, super scripts, &hellip;).

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX loads math fonts and assigns them on demand so you need to have an initial math setup to ensure that there is a font to be used as scriptfont. Also you want fam 1 not 0 in the usual setup.

I don't recommend that you do this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\showoutput

\def\bfscript#1{%
\setbox0\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mathbf{\xdef\tmp{\the\scriptfont\fam}}$}%
\hbox{$\scriptfont1=\tmp #1$}}

$\bfscript{v_i}$

$v_{\mathbf{i}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah!  I was close then; just had the wrong font number.  Thanks very much David. Of COURSE I won't use that. Probably. :-)